# How to delete a complete entry from json array at run-time

Tags: java, json

I want to delete a JSON-array record at run-time by providing the values to remove.

I have tried the following code but it is adding a `/` on each  values;

Original Json File:
`{"Products":[{"p10":"SamsungS5"},{"i6":"Iphone6"}]}`

After performing the delete operation, the output becomes:
`{"Products":[["{\"p10\":\"SamsungS5\"}","{\"i6\":\"Iphone6\"}"]]}`

The code for the remove method is:

```
public static void removeSearchedClass(String value ) throws IOException, ParseException, InvocationTargetException {


        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj; 


        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
        JSONArray solutions = (JSONArray) jo.get("Products");
        int len = solutions.size();
        if (solutions != null) { 
           for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
            list.add(solutions.get(i).toString());
           } 
        }
                list.remove(value.trim());

        solutions.clear();
        solutions.add(list);

        jo.put("Products", solutions);

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, false);
        file.append(jo.toString());
        file.flush();
        file.close(); 
         }
```

When I enter "Iphone6", I need the complete entry for Iphone6, which is `{"i6":"Iphone6"}`, to be deleted.

Comment: How is this related to JavaFX? What are the import declarations for `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`?

Comment: Actually the calling program is written in javafx, but you are right here no usage of javafx is visible so please ignore about javafx. Iam using simple json for import.

Comment: But iam not bound to use simple json, if solution could be possible using any other library, i will easily add.

Comment: You have not answered my question about the JSON classes which are not in JavaSE.

Comment: Iam sorry but iam not getting about your question; however iam using org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.simple.JSONArray for jsonobject and jsonarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) ([JSR-374](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374)), which is part of the JavaEE (now [EE4J](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j)) specs, you can you the following:

```
String jsonString = "{\"Products\":[{\"p10\":\"SamsungS5\"},{\"i6\":\"Iphone6\"}]}";
String removeValue = "\"Iphone6\"";

JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
JsonObject jsonObj = jsonReader.readObject();

JsonPatchBuilder builder = Json.createPatchBuilder();

JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJsonArray("Products"); // [{"p10":"SamsungS5"},{"i6":"Iphone6"}]
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject entry = jsonArray.get(i).asJsonObject();
    for (JsonValue value : entry.values()) {
        if (value.toString().equals(removeValue)) {
            builder.remove("/Products/" + i);
        }
    }
}

JsonPatch patch = builder.build();
JsonObject newObj = patch.apply(jsonObj);
System.out.println(newObj); // {"Products":[{"p10":"SamsungS5"}]}
```

The "Products" array contains JSON entries (a key-value pair, like `{"i6":"Iphone6"}`). You then iterate over the values of each entry (though there is only one: `"Iphone6"`). If it matches the one you want to remove, you modify the patch to remove the index of that entry. Then apply the patch on the JSON object.

The dependencies are the specification, like JavaEE:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and an implementation of JSON-P, like Glassfish:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```